# On rendering from controller, current_page method does not seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a navigation bar included in `application.html.erb`. Because for some pages, such as the signup page, I need to place additional code inside the navigation bar, I have excluded those pages for showing the navigation bar through `application.html.erb` and instead included it in their respective view pages. See code below.

A problem arises when invalid data is entered in the signup form. The controller method then renders `new`. However, `application.html.erb` then doesn't seem to recognize that the current_page is still `signup_path`, therefore not applying the exception for not showing the navigation bar on that page. As a result when it renders new, the navigation bar is shown twice: once by order of `application.html.erb` and once by order of the view page itself.

Why, when rendering new on an invalid form entry, does it not see that it's still on `signup_path`? How should I adjust my code so that it does not show the navigation bar twice in that situation? Is there perhaps a way of including `<%= yield special code if any %>` in `application.html.erb` and `<% special_code %> <% end special_code %>` in the view page that passes this special code to `application.html.erb`?

---

In application.html.erb I have:

```
<% unless current_page?(signup_path) %>
  <nav class="banner">
    <%= render partial: "shared/header" %>
  </nav>
<% end %>
```

In the view of my signup page:

```
<nav class="banner">
    <%= render partial: "shared/header" %>
    Additional code that needs to be within 'nav' for this page
</nav>
```

Controller method:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @stakeholder.save
    flash[:success] = "A confirmation email has been sent to you."
    redirect_to root_url
  else                          
    render 'new'  ###This is where it goes wrong!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `content_for` and `yields` to create a default in your layout which views can override.

```
# layouts/application.html.erb:
<% if content_for?(:banner) %>
  <%= yield(:banner) %>
<% else %>
  <div id="banner">
    <h1>This is the default...</h1>
  </div>
<% end %>

/users/signup.html.erb:
<%- content_for :banner, flush: true do -%>
  <!-- move along, nothing to see here -->
<%- end -%>
```

The advantage here is that you don't end up turning your layouts into a birds nest of conditionals. You can easily just inject whatever you want into the layout from views.

The cons are that you have to use a stupid hack with a HTML comment to *override the block to display nothing* since `content_for?` trims the block. `content_for` does not play nice with fragment catching either.

## addded

I didn't touch on this before `unless current_page?(signup_path)` does not work as you expect since `render 'new'` does not magically move you to the new action. In fact the current_path is `/users` since the form POST's to that url.

It just tells rails to find a template named 'new' and render it.

A corrected version would be:

```
<% unless controller_name == 'users' && ['new', 'create'].include?( action_name) %>
  <nav class="banner">
   <%= render partial: "shared/header" %>
  </nav>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great, I think I got it to work! I'm not sure about two things though: 1) Didn't understand what you meant regarding the HTML comment. There's no need to include the `move along` line, or is there? On pages that have nothing to add to the banner, I have not included the `content_for` code, while on pages that do have something to add the code to add is there instead of the `move along` line. Is this correct?  2) Searched to understand fragment catching a bit better. Is this a serious issue? I don't think my app is using this or is this used generally by everyone by default?

Comment: Edited the question - I hope it makes the "comment hack" part more understandable. Fragment caching is not something that is just "turned on" or off. Rather you find parts of the view that seldom change and speed up rendering by caching that chunk of the view. A common use case would be for example if you have a dropdown menu which displays all Pages. You can use fragment caching to avoid querying for the pages and re-rendering the menu unless Pages.all has changes (it uses something called a cache digest).

Comment: Whether this is a deal breaker or not depends on your requirements.

Comment: And the issue is actually that "#content_for is ignored in caches. So you shouldn't use it for elements that will be fragment cached." Not that it breaks fragment caching on the entire page. I might have been a bit unclear on that.

Comment: Thanks Maxcal. I think I will then go for your added, alternative solution. Because the part within `content_for` a.o. contains a large carousel on the home page. And since users might visit the home page a lot, I think it's important for that part to have caching to work well for that part of the code.

Comment: On loading the page, I got the error message `undefined method 'includes?'`. Changing it to `include?` solved it. Typo in your solution?

Comment: Yes its a typo. I keep making that same one over and over... Damn brain!

Answer (score -1):

You are completely right. This is where it goes wrong

```
render 'new'  ###This is where it goes wrong!
```

Here's what happens

1. user requests a `new` action, which renders the `new` template
2. user submits the form, thus requesting the `create` action in your controller
3. inside your `create` action you render your `new` template instead of `create` when validation fails

So basically user is no longer on the `new` page, but on the `create` page with a view rendered from `new`.

The easiest solution would be to change expectation for the header to both `new` and `create` actions, since you redirect on success, so you won't use it otherwise.

Comment: While the top part of answer is excellent It totally falls apart at "The easiest solution would be to change expectation for the header to both new and create actions, since you redirect on success, so you won't use it otherwise.". This wording here is very confusing but could be salvaged by an edit.